# "Unhandled promise rejection" error when installing ionic 2 plugins

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, onesignal

I get the following error during installation of the Cordova OneSignal plugin:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I couldn't find any solutions on Google.

Comment: I saw too much people facing this issue but there isn't any fix. I'm facing this but I really don't know where should I look. Is there any clue? debugging tip?